# Showing $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = O_p(\sqrt{n})$ if $E[y_i] = 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = O_p(n)$ if $E[y_i] \neq 0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Let $y_1,\dots,y_n$ be a set of i.i.d random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Can it be shown that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = O_p(\sqrt{n}), & \quad \quad \text{if} \ E[y_i] = 0, \\
\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = O_p(n), & \quad \quad \text{if} \ E[y_i] \neq 0.
\end{align}
$$ using the definition of convergence in probability for Big $O_p$ notation?

I saw a simplified explanation for the results in page 4 of [these notes](https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/magee/761_762/other%20material/asy%20concepts.pdf) but I'm wondering can it be done directly using the the definition of $O_p$, i.e. $X_n = O_p(n)$ if for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $M,N>0$ such that $P(|X_n/n|>M) < \varepsilon$ for all $n > N$.

Comment: Do yow CLT & LLN?

Comment: Ok thanks I see why now.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about one thing in my answer below, which is can we say that $\mu = O_p(1)$.

Comment: I don't think so: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/239288/290189

Comment: I actually think a constant is $O_p(1)$ now. Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of random variables where $X_n = \mu \in \mathbb{R}$. Then clearly for any $\varepsilon >0$, if we take $M>|\mu|$ it holds that $P(|X_n| > M) = P(|\mu| > M) = 0 < \varepsilon$ for all $n$.

Comment: In section 2.3 of the linked notes, it's state that their mean is $\mu$.  I suppose that means $\mu\in\Bbb{R}$.  That's not included in your question body.

Comment: I've edited my post to include that now.

Comment: I don't get it.  Say $X \sim \mathrm{Ber}(p)$ with $p \in (0,1)$, so $\mu = p$ and $\sigma^2 = p(1-p)$.  I take $M = (p+1)/2 \in (p,1)$.  $P(|X| > M) \ge P(X = 1) = p > 0$.

Comment: You have a random variable that takes on the value either $0$ or $1$. On the other hand, my sequence of constant random variables $X_n$ only ever takes on one value which is the constant $\mu$. Thus once we take $M$ to be larger than $|\mu|$ the probability of $|\mu|$ being larger than $M$ is always zero.

Comment: oh you have "where ..." that follows $X_n$.  but I don't think that's the intention of the course instructor.  that's too restrictive

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying? My answer below shows why the results in my question hold. I was unsure about one aspect of my answer which is whether a constant can be considered an $O_p(1)$ random variable, but now I think a constant is indeed $O_p(1)$ based on my comments above. So it seems everything is ok now.

Comment: A constant is $O(1)$ (deterministic), so ...

Comment: A constant can be considered a constant random variable with a [degenerate distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution) so I think we can apply the $O_p$ notation to it.

Answer (score 1):

The CLT says
$$
n^{1/2}\bigg(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i - \mu\bigg) \stackrel{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma^2).
$$
Since the term on the left hand side converges in distribution it is bounded in probability:
$$
n^{1/2}\bigg(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i - \mu\bigg) = O_p(1)
$$
which menas
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i = \mu + O_p(n^{-1/2}) & \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n y_i = n\mu + O_p(n^{1/2}).
\end{align}
$$
Now if $E[y_i] = 0$ we get the rate $O_p(n^{1/2})$. Otherwise $\mu = O_p(1)$ since it is a 'constant random variable' and thus
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = nO_p(1) + O_p(n^{1/2}) = O_p(n).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Actually I'm not sure we can say $\mu = O_p(1)$.